# Nextjs config: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm having this problem while importing `stream-chat` modules to my app.

I got a legacy code config and I've seen similar here cases but I'm not sure how I'm going to apply the suggested fixes in my `next.config.js`.

From other posts:

I'm supposed to install `npm i css-loader file-loader url-loader -D` and then wrap my module `module.exports` inside `withCSS({})`.

[Webpack 4 - Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927674/webpack-4-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character)

[NextJS Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (7:0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455259/nextjs-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character-70)

The error(s)

```
> [ error ]
> ./node_modules/stream-chat-react/dist/assets/Poweredby_100px-White_VertText.png
> 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need
> an appropriate loader to handle this file type. (Source code omitted
> for this binary file) ModuleParseError: Module parse failed:
> Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to
> handle this file type. (Source code omitted for this binary file)
> 
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (4:0) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type. | /* colors */ | /*
> miscellaneous */
> > @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans:400,400i,700,700i");
```

And my `next.config.js`

```
const { withPlugins, optional } = require('next-compose-plugins')
const { PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD } = require('next-server/constants')
const sass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const images = require('next-images') // update
const css = require('@zeit/next-css') // also added this plugin
const { requireEnvVar } = require('./lib/nodeUtils')

const nextConfig = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    ...
  },

  useFileSystemPublicRoutes: false,

  webpack(config, { webpack }) {
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /en/)
    )

    return config
  },
}

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [sass],
    [images], // tried this with images
    [css], // also tried with css
    [
      optional(() => require('@zeit/next-bundle-analyzer')),
      {
        analyzeServer: ['server', 'both'].includes(process.env.BUNDLE_ANALYZE),
        analyzeBrowser: ['browser', 'both'].includes(
          process.env.BUNDLE_ANALYZE
        ),
        bundleAnalyzerConfig: {
          server: {
            analyzerMode: 'static',
            reportFilename: '../../bundles/server.html',
          },
          browser: {
            analyzerMode: 'static',
            reportFilename: '../bundles/client.html',
          },
        },
      },
      [PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD],
    ],
  ],
  nextConfig
)
```

Also tried `const css = require('@zeit/next-css')` and `const images = require('next-images')` then adding it next to `sass` in the first array of `withPlugins` like so: `withPlugins([[sass], css, images ,[...]);` with no success.

Thanks as always!

Comment: You need an appropriate loader to import `.png` files, using `next-images` should take care of that. Can you show your full config when you try to use `next-images`?

Comment: Sure, it is updated now. Thanks in advance